# Update Field based on Same Field not Null

Tags: sql, oracle

Apologize for the terrible title. Unsure how to express my need succinctly. I know there is an answer for this with MySQL, but it does not work for Oracle

I have a table where my OrderID field is not distinct as it by line item on the order. When a user deletes certain line items from the order and approves the order, I get a completion date for the line item that was approved, and a null value for those deleted. I need to update the completiondate for all of the lines on that order. This is what it looks like

[image]

And this is what I am looking for

[image]

I have found code that will update if I pick a specific OrderID, but if I open it up to scan the entire table, it will take 35 hrs (not feasible, obviously)

```
update batchmgr.udt_buyer a set a.completedate=(select b.completedate from batchmgr.udt_buyer b where b.completedate is not null and b.orderid=a.orderid) where a.orderid ='221292540';
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
update batchmgr.udt_buyer b
    set completedate = (select b2.completedate
                        from batchmgr.udt_buyer b2
                        where b2.completedate is not null and
                              b2.orderid = b.orderid and
                              rownum = 1
                       )
    where b.orderid = '221292540' and b.completedate is null;
```

For performance, you want an index on `(orderid, completate)`.

Also, be sure that `orderid` is a string.  If not drop the single quotes on the constant coparison.

Comment: Thank you! I had to index on orderid, item, and completedate due to duplicates, but it worked beautifully after that

Answer (score 0):

I would use `max()` just in case if you have different completion dates for the same order:

```sql
update batchmgr.udt_buyer a 
set a.completedate=(select max(b.completedate)
                    from   batchmgr.udt_buyer b 
                    where b.completedate is not null 
                      and b.orderid=a.orderid) 
where a.orderid ='221292540';
```

Or you can create a view with analytic function `max() over` to get the same without updates:

```sql
create or replace view v_order_items as 
select
    OrderId
    ,Buyer
    ,OrderType
    ,Item
    ,CreateDate
    ,max(CompleteDate)over(partition by OrderId) as CompleteDate
from batchmgr.udt_buyer;
```

But it would be better to **normalize** your data and store orders separately from order items.