# Update column with values from field in the same table if field is not null

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-update

Thank you all in advance, I have been trying to use the query in the post below to update null values in the name_field column using the same column only if the values are not null

[Update Field based on Same Field not Null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67215386/update-field-based-on-same-field-not-null)

My table has ParcelID_Field, Name_Field and Address_Field sometimes the Namefield is blank. The address and ID fields are always populated. Whenever the Name field Is NULL I would like to use the information that is there to populate the NULL fields

This query almost works, but its says 0 rows affected when ran. The select within the ( ) works perfectly just no values are updated.

```
update [DMSEngine].[dbo].[IndexForm_ePermitsResults] 
set Name_Field = (select b2.Name_Field
                    from [DMSEngine].[dbo].[IndexForm_ePermitsResults] b2
                    where b2.Name_Field is not null and
                          b2.ParcelID_Field = ParcelID_Field and
                          ParcelID_Field = 12257
                   )
where ParcelID_Field = 12257 and Name_Field is null;
```

| ParcelID_Field | Name_Field | AddressField |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 111 | smith | 1 street name |
| 111 |  | 1 street name |
| 111 |  | 1 street name |
| 111 | smith | 1 street name |
| 222 |  | 3 street name |
| 222 | jacobs | 3 street name |
| 222 |  | 3 street name |
| 222 |  | 3 street name |

Comment: Also when I put RowNum=1 I get and Invalid column and if I use update [DMSEngine].[dbo].[IndexForm_ePermitsResults] b I get incorrect syntax expecting SET

Comment: Also tried this, Update [DMSEngine].[dbo].[IndexForm_ePermitsResults]
SET Name_Field = CASE WHEN Name_Field IS NOT NULL THEN Name_Field ELSE Name_Field END
FROM [DMSEngine].[dbo].[IndexForm_ePermitsResults]
where ParcelID_Field = 12257

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. The select was off as intimated by the posted who questioned above. So I changed the select statement but even that threw an error. Subquery returned more that 1 value. This is not permitted... So I read up on that error and included MAX in my query and it worked.

The correct answer is

```
update [DMSEngine].[dbo].[IndexForm_ePermitsResults] 
set Name_Field = (select MAX (b2.Name_Field)
                from [DMSEngine].[dbo].[IndexForm_ePermitsResults] b2
                where b2.Name_Field <>'' and
                      b2.ParcelID_Field = ParcelID_Field and
                      ParcelID_Field = 12257
               )
where ParcelID_Field = 12257 and Name_Field = ' ';
```

Answer (score 0):

When editing the data in the table, try the Select query alone first, so you can know if it returns the right data.

About this query: Why do you have "ParcelID_Field = 12257"? This "where" condition will give you only a field where the Name_Field is null AND ParcelID_Field is 12257.

Comment: Thanks for taking a look at my question, yes the Select query works great. It selects  all of the Smiths and Jacobs as well as the NULL values. Yes I put in the Where clause so that I could test it on a small set of data I didn't to run it on the entire table until I knew it worked.

Comment: I even tried it where I changed the select statement to this select b2.Name_Field
                    from [DMSEngine].[dbo].[IndexForm_ePermitsResults] b2
                    where b2.Name_Field >'' and
                          b2.ParcelID_Field = ParcelID_Field and
                          ParcelID_Field = 12257  I removed the IS NOT NULL and replaced it with <>'' and that only returned the smiths and jacobs.

Comment: I saw you figured it out! Happy for you, good luck!